# JSF + ajax обновление таблицы

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

есть таблица где напротив каждой строки есть кнопка удалить. нужно использовать ajax чтобы обновлялась таблица с убранной строкой.

```
<h:form id="PriceForm">
    <h:dataTable id="PriceTable" binding="#{table}" value="#{priceBean.pricesList()}" var="Price"
                 class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered tableUpdated">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + 1}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Price.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{Price.value}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Update</f:facet>
            <h:commandButton action="#{priceBean.editPriceRecord(Price.id)}" value="Update"
                             class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
            <h:commandButton action="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(Price.id)}" value="Delete"
                             class="btn btn-danger"></h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton action="createPrice.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" value="Create New User"
                     class="btn btn-success btnSpace"/>

</h:form>
```

я внедрил в блок с кнопкой delete такую конструкцию

```
    <f:ajax execute = "PriceTable" render = "@form" />
```

но не очень понимаю что нужно вписать в execute  и render  чтобы работало.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton update=":PriceForm:PriceTable"
                                 actionListener="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(Price.id)}" value="Delete"
                                 class="btn btn-danger">
                </h:commandButton>
```

нужно было добавить update=ссылка на форму и на таблицу в ней